# textfield looks blurry when moves

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield, blurry

The textfield is used to show the player name and added to the player sprite. When the player moves, the name textfield looks blurry and the font is the default font.

I tried drawing the textfield to bitmapdata, but it looks same.

are there any ways to optimize this?

**EDIT**

I found the problem. When the player moves, the map moves to keep the player in the center position of the map. Sometimes the map doesn't move with the same offset x and offset y to the player, so player looks like blurry.

But when the player moves on the edge of the map, it looks blurry, and I haven't found an solution to this.

Comment: Sometimes, ensuring that the `TextField`'s `x` and `y` properties are set to whole (integer) pixel values helps. You can also play around with the `TextField`'s `cacheAsBitmap` and `antiAliasType` properties.

Comment: I agree with Marcela. Also try using Embedded fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting anti-aliasing option to **anti-alias for readability** on the text field. For some reason **anti-alias for animation** is default (at least it use to be).

It has also been my experience that you need to set the x/y location of text fields to be a whole number. Meaning no subpixel locations like 10.3 or 567.8. Rather make sure it locks to whole numbers like 10 or 567.